# Ошибка IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

Имею код

```
import random
import numpy as np


class people:
    __slots__ = "name", "age", "gold", "ids", "location"

    def __init__(self, ids, name, age, gold, location):
        self.ids = ids
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gold = gold
        self.location = location


    def __str__(self):
        return "ID: {} | Имя: {} | Возраст: {} | Денег: {} | Локация: {}".format(self.ids, self.name, self.age,
                                                                                 self.gold, self.location)

    __repr__ = __str__


def getLocation():   # *проблемное место*
    loca = random.randint(0, len(location))
    locaPeople[loca] += 1

    return location[loca]


location = [f"Место_{i}" for i in range(10)] # нужно.
locaPeople = [0 for i in range(len(location))]

pepl = [people(i, f"Человек_{i}", random.randint(18, 90), random.randint(1, 1000), getLocation()) for i in range(500000)]
```

из за чего происходить ошибка
**IndexError: list index out of range**?

И как можно её исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Т.к. `randint` генерирует число в границах: `a <= randint() <= b`, то есть вероятность, что будет снегерировано число `b`. А элемента под таким индексом не существует.  Поэтому нам надо подвинуть правую границу на `-1`, так `loca = random.randint(0, len(location) - 1)`

```
import random
import numpy as np


class people:
    __slots__ = "name", "age", "gold", "ids", "location"

    def __init__(self, ids, name, age, gold, location):
        self.ids = ids
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gold = gold
        self.location = location


    def __str__(self):
        return "ID: {} | Имя: {} | Возраст: {} | Денег: {} | Локация: {}".format(self.ids, self.name, self.age,
                                                                                 self.gold, self.location)

    __repr__ = __str__


def getLocation():   # *проблемное место*
    loca = random.randint(0, len(location) - 1) # изменил
    locaPeople[loca] += 1

    return location[loca]


location = [f"Место_{i}" for i in range(10)] # нужно.
locaPeople = [0 for i in range(len(location))]

pepl = [people(i, f"Человек_{i}", random.randint(18, 90), random.randint(1, 1000), getLocation()) for i in range(500000)]
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117417/discussion-on-answer-by-entithat--indexerror-list-index-out-of-range).